# AccessibilityNodeInfo getText() always given null

Tags: java, android, accessibility

Recently i am looking for accessibility function. Everything working fine but now AccessibilityNodeInfo getText() method always return null on scroll event before that it return all the component on scroll event like all the value in my window..

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = accessibilityEvent.getSource();
    if (nodeInfo != null)
        System.out.println("data : "+nodeInfo.getText());
```

Need some clarification for any changes made on accessibility event because its worked fine yesterday and i am new to Accessibility Event.Following my accessibility service info

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds|flagRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:description="@string/accessibility_description" />
```

Comment: I have a same problem. Do you solution it? Can you help me.